# REST not working in AWS on Maven Project. Just locally

Tags: java, rest, maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So I created a Maven Project in NetBeans. Deployed to Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. I created the GET service (Working perfect locally) which connects to the Oracle DB.

[image: Define Rest]

Here's the code I use to access the GET service from my index, it works while deploying locally:

[image: AJAX]

And the method call with the URI:

```
 self.ajax("http://127.0.0.1:8080/webresources/kpis/first/09/09/1994/second/20/02/2017", 'GET').done(function(data) {
  alert(data);
 });
```

(When running in locally y add /mavenproject1/ between 8080 and webresources).

However,when deploying and running the code I can't get result. Chrome shows me this error in console "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" (I suppose its because it can't find localhost while deployed). I believe its because it can't find localhost and it treats the REST as if it was a Cross-Domain Request.

[image: ERROR CHROME]

I need to connect my FrontEnd with backend without exposing my REST to anybody. Can someone help me?

Thanks.

Comment: In your last screenshot the IP address it is trying to hit is 0.0.0.0. That's obviously incorrect. "I need to connect my FrontEnd with backend without exposing my REST to anybody." Your FrontEnd runs in the browser, correct? How exactly are you configuring that AJAX call in the browser to know what the address is for the REST service?

Comment: @Juan David Cruz Serrano . I am facing the same problem. Did you resolve this? My service is working perfectly fine on my local but when deployed on EC2 it give me 404 and says service not found. This is driving me crazy. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @HiteshBhutani I did resolved the problem. Instead of using PathParam and a URL with the parameters separated by "/". User QueryParam and use the self.ajax("/webresources/kpis/first?day=01&month=02&year=12"). etc

Answer (score 0):

Your front end code is is going to have to call the IP address of the host on which the backend code runs.  There's no way around that. But if the front end back ends are served by the same process, then you can use relative urls in your ajax calls:

```
self.ajax("/webresources/kpis/first/09/09/1994/second/20/02/2017", 'GET')
    .done(function(data) {
         alert(data);
 });
```

GET calls will be accessible to public callers, but none of the other HTTP verbs.  You can specify fine grained control by setting up CORS headers on your server. However, if you are using ajax  you are pretty much going to have expose all the verbs used by your api to any and all callers.

If you want more control over who can call your api, you have to look into a token based access system like JWT, where only authenticated clients can call your api endpoints by appending a token to the headers sent with requests.